# ASP.Net Core MVC Layout Issue

Tags: layout, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a layout page which has a top menu and a side navbar. My problem is when I've created a new razor view (content page). It seems to be centering from the whole page not taking into account the sidebar. Also my div container in my content page does not user all the screen. Am I missing something. I thought if I create my layout page with a side bar the content page would use the remaining page.

Thanks for any help,

Layout Code:-

```html
<body>
    <nav id="menuBar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color:white;">Building ********</a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                           data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Manage
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration"
                               asp-action="ListUsers">Users</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration"
                               asp-action="ListRoles">Roles</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <form method="post" asp-controller="account" asp-action="logout">
                            <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0" style="width:auto;">
                                Logout @User.Identity.Name
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                }
                else
                {
                    @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="account" asp-action="register" class="nav-link">Register</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a asp-controller="account" asp-action="login" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    @*Sidebar*@
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    </div>
    <div class="container mt-3 mb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

I've added an image of the layout I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Please share your layout page

Comment: Layout Page Code Added, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below:

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <nav id="menuBar" class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color:white;">Building ********</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
                    @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                    {
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                               data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                Manage
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration"
                                   asp-action="ListUsers">Users</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Administration"
                                   asp-action="ListRoles">Roles</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    }
                    @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                    {
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <form method="post" asp-controller="account" asp-action="logout">
                                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0" style="width:auto;">
                                    Logout @User.Identity.Name
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                        {
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a asp-controller="account" asp-action="register" class="nav-link">Register</a>
                            </li>
                        }
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a asp-controller="account" asp-action="login" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately that didn't work. My navbar did not stretch to the full width of the screen, there is no dashboard strip on the left and my first content page (login) is positioned far right.